# Boolean question

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean

So, I'm working on teaching myself jQuery with the help of some books, and I'm currently stumped by a seemingly simple problem. Why does the value of `$('div.foo').length` evaluate to 0? A `div` element exists in the page, so why doesn't the `$('div.foo').length` evaluate to 1?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write($(div.foo).length);
            </script>
    <body>
            <div class="foo"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: the DOM isn't loaded yet.

You have two options:

1. place the code just before the `</body>` tag so the document elements have been loaded and, thus, jQuery has visibility of the object.
2. Use `$(document).ready(function(){ ...code... })` (or short-hand `$(function(){ ...code... })` so the code within the braces only executes after the document is loaded.

Try these two on for size:

**re-ordering executon:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="foo">
    <script>
      alert($('.foo').length);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**wait for loaded DOM***

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        alert($('.foo').length);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="foo">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 document.write($(div.foo).length)
```

should be

```
 document.write($("div.foo").length);
```

And also, your scipt will be run before the DOM is loaded, so try encapsulating the JavaScript in jQuery's [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) - see http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3AIntroducing_%24(document).ready()

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the quotes

```
document.write($("div.foo").length);
```

Edit:

Brad makes a good point. You should wrap this call in `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    document.write($("div.foo").length);
});
```

Comment: Though you're right about quotes, the DOM isn't fully loaded yet. It still won't see the element.

Comment: @Brad: Edited to add more info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to **move this code after dom elements are created**, by moving it at bottom before `body` tag. Currently you are try to access elements even before they are created in DOM.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write($('div.foo').length);
   </script>
```

**or**

Run your code after DOM is ready i.e. all elements are created in DOM.

```
//this piece of code can be placed even before elements are created
    $(function(){
    //this code here, will run after DOM is ready
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

DOM is not loaded. Use

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
          alert($('div.foo').length); 
    });
```